# Rellenar input con registro de una tabla en sql server al cargar el formulario evento load proyecto

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, mvc

Se requiere que cuando carga el formulario de la imagen, en el evento load, el input [TxtCor] debe cargar el correlativo que se trae de la Base de Datos. En este caso debe traer = 00001. En el input no me muestra el correlativo, he tratado de descartar de diferente maneras pero no logro resolver el problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
//-- Procedimiento almacenado
Alter Proc SpGecCot
As
   Begin Transaction
          Declare @CorCot Varchar (6)
          Set @CorCot = (Select Isnull(Max(VE_COCREG),0) From VE0005COTC)
          Set @CorCot = Right('00000'+ Cast(Cast(@CorCot As Varchar)+1 As VarChar(6)),5)
          Select @CorCot
     Commit Transaction
  Return
Go
```

```js
//-- Código Modelo
  public List<VenCoc> ObtCor()
  {
      List<VenCoc> CotCor = new List<VenCoc>();
      using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Conexi.cx))
      {
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SpGecCot", con);
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          try
          {
              con.Open();
              SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
              //while (dr.Read())
              //{
              //    CotCor.Add(new VenCoc()
              //    {
              //        CocCor = Convert.ToString(dr["@CorCot"].ToString()),
              //    });
              //}
              dr.Close();
              return CotCor;
          }catch (Exception ex){
              CotCor = null;
              return CotCor;
          }
      }
  }
```

```js
 //--Obtener Correlativo.
  jQuery.ajax({
      url: "/Ventas/CotCor"+ $("#TxtCor").val().load(),
      type: "GET",
      data: null,
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function (result) {
          /*if (data.data != null) {*/
              /*$("#totalhabitaciones").text(data.data.length)*/
          $("#TxtCor").val(result);
          return resultado;
        /*  }*/
      },
      error: function (error) {
          console.log(error)
      },
      beforeSend: function () {
      },
  });
```

-- Código del Controlador

```js
  //ObtCor(String CocCor)
  public ActionResult CotCor()
  { try {
          List<VenCoc> oLista = VenCotDB.Instancia.ObtCor();
          return Json(new { lista = oLista }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      }catch (Exception ex){
          return Json(new { esErrror = true, mensaje = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      }
  }
```

Comment: y qué problema hay?

Comment: Hola Nicolas, el problema es que no me muestra el input el correlativo que lo debe de traer de la Base de Datos. he descartado de diferentes formas pero creo que estoy fallando en el ajax y en el modelo.

Comment: Nicolas por favor me podras apoyar descartando el problema al parecer es en el ajax cuando lo estoy llamando en el evento.

Comment: adicional cuando cargo el formulario ni siquiera entra a la funcion del ajax.

Comment: creo que tu problema esta aquí: `url: "/Ventas/CotCor"+ $("#TxtCor").val().load(),` debería ser `url: "/Ventas/CotCor"` para invocar bien al controlador

Comment: Hola Nicolas he probado con las indicaciones mencionadas pero sigue con el problema.

Comment: comprueba si `List<VenCoc> oLista = VenCotDB.Instancia.ObtCor();` te está obteniendo resultados con un punto de parada

Comment: Hola Nicolas, de acuerdo lo que mencionas puse un punto de parada y si recibe el correlativo, en el input me pinta [objec] pero no me muestra el correlativo.